# How to know if methods have been added to a class

Tags: ruby, methods

I used the library [rest_client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to query an http server:

```
r = RestClient.get 'http://stackoverflow.com'
```

Unless the server returns an error code, `r` is a string with the http answer:

```
r # => I get the HTML, no HTTP headers, no HTTP status code
r.class # => "String"
```

As the doc points out, `r` responds to the following methods:

```
r.code
r.headers
r.raw_header
```

among other http specific stuff. How can I have evidence of what has been added to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see if methods were added to the instance, you compare its methods with its class's instance methods:

```
r.methods - r.class.instance_methods
#  => [:args, :args, :body, :body, :net_http_res, :net_http_res, :code, :headers, :raw_headers, :cookies, :return!, :description, :follow_redirection] 

str = 'a'
str.methods - str.class.instance_methods
# => []
```

Comment: If you wanted to see the singleton methods, then `r.singleton_methods` would be better. But the question seems to be asking about ordinary instance methods.

Comment: @sawa, ok, but this is what I wanted, that is the methods that are in r but are not in 'regular' string. By the way, singleton_methods differs from this "subctraction" case by having ":to_i" method in addition.

Answer (score 1):

A look at the [source code](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/response.rb#L17) reveals that REST Client adds methods to the result string by calling [`extend`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-extend):

```
def Response.create body, net_http_res, args
  result = body || ''
  result.extend Response
  result.net_http_res = net_http_res
  result.args = args
  result
end
```

This adds the instance methods from [`RestClient::Resonse`](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/response.rb) and the included [`RestClient::AbstractResponse`](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb).

API docs:

- http://rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/RestClient/Response
- http://rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/RestClient/AbstractResponse

BTW, you can always look up a method with [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-method):

```
r = RestClient.get 'http://stackoverflow.com'
r.method(:code)
#=> #<Method: String(RestClient::AbstractResponse)#code>
r.method(:args)
#=> #<Method: String(RestClient::Response)#code>

require 'json'
r.method(:to_json)
#=> #<Method: String(JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::String)#to_json>
```